import module in an other one VS
I am trying to call a module into another one in the same folder in Visual Studio. I'm working in maya
I have tried (see image for naming and code example):
import os # works fine
import "nameofthisfolder" # error
from ."moduleinthisfolder" import "function" # error

It says that the module doesn't exist.
Does anyone have an answer about that or I'm just not using it in the good way ?
Thanks
Image showing my code and file structure

minimal-reproducible-example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to put a file named __init__.py in the /lookDev folder, which tells Python the folder is a package and allows the files to be called as modules.  Within your module folder you will now call functions from other modules from within the folder using:
import os
# import "modulefolder" - remove this line in your code
from ."moduleinfolder" import "functionname"

Note: Make sure that each module doesn't import from other modules that import from it, as you will continue to get the "module not found" error.
For external use, if you want your module to only call specific files, you can import those files into __init__.py specifically, using either:
from . import file1
from . import file2
from . import file2
__all__ = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'] # this line is redundant in this example, but can be useful for further limitin imports for external code

then call the module using the following (assuming the run file is in the same parent directory as module!):
from .module import file1, file3

to import specific modules, or:
from .module import *

to import all the modules. Either way functions will be called using file1.funct1, file2.funct3, etc.
Alternatively (not recommended for external API development or complex codebases) you can set up __init__.py like this:
from .file1 import *
from .file2 import *
from .file3 import *

and then you can import all functions using from .module import *. But now funct1 will be called using funct1, not file1.funct1.
NOTE: Any files or functions starting with _ will not be incorporated into the * import even if they are in the __all__ list.  To use _functions or _modules, you will have to call the module specifically, not using from module import *.
